# ASP .NET bind complex type property from form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, data-binding, razor-pages

I have a `Book` class:

```
public class Book
{
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

And I have `cshtml` input

```
<select asp-items="Model.Genres" asp-for="Book.Genre" class="custom-select">
</select>
```

But after `POSTing` this request I get null in `Author` and `Book` attributes. How can I bind this?

Answer (score 1):

**Is your Genre an `enum` type?**

***If it is not an enumeration, but a common type like the following:***

```
public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then if you just want to bind a complex type property from form, you only need to bind directly.

Example:

```
<form method="post">
<input asp-for="Book.Genre.Id" />
<input asp-for="Book.Genre.Name" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

***If you want to use dropdownlist.You can change your code like below.***

PageModel:

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Genres { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
       Genres = new List<SelectListItem>
         {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "AA", Text = "AA" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "BB", Text = "BB" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "CC", Text = "CC"  },
         };
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<form method="post">
<input asp-for="Book.Genre.Id" />

<select asp-items="Model.Genres" asp-for="Book.Genre.Name" class="custom-select">
</select>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

***If your Genre is an enum type like:***

```
public enum Genre
{    
    Mexico,
    USA,
    Canada,
    France,
    Germany,
    Spain
}
```

You can change your page code to:

```
<form method="post">
<select asp-for="Book.Genre"
        asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Models.Genre>()">
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

to bind `Book`.

***You can see details in [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-select-tag-helper)***

Comment: I want to display already created authors and genres in select and I got it. Now i want to bind this FK to new created book object and dont make duplicate of author and genre.

Comment: Use `asp-for="the property you want bind"`,then it will bind the value of the dropdownlist.

Comment: Hi @salvatore, If you have other requirements, please provide your class and detailed information.

Comment: I have `Book` class that contains `Genre` object. `POST` new book requires chosing from `select` element alredy existing genre. After posting book should be added to database with attribute genre as foreign key.

Comment: Check the documentation to understand model binding